# Deserialize Json likes from friends of facebook asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, facebook

i need to deserialize a json string from facebook that i get from the graph:

```
{
"id": "1741240583",
"music": {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "KMN | Kill My Name",
            "id": "168949476496447",
            "created_time": "2013-05-01T07:30:54+0000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Hocus Pocus",
            "id": "174462922710692",
            "created_time": "2013-04-16T17:55:46+0000"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

the way i have did is like this:

```
    public class Result
    {
        public Music music { get; set; }
    }

    public class Music
    {
        public Data[] data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string[] name { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string teste = "{\"id\": \"723560709\",\"music\": {\"data\": [{\"name\": \"LOKO  ( Life Opium Kill over )\",\"id\": \"129518483779162\",\"created_time\": \"2013-05-07T02:54:39+0000\"},],}}";

        Result soap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(teste);
```

but it returns this error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'GuiaDePresentes.Buscape.Buscape_Controle+Data' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'music.data', line 1, position 38.
```

how can i make this thing work?

PS:yeah, i am a newbie in programming :D

Comment: changing the classes music and data, now i get another error:
Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.String[].

i have changed this:


   public class Music
        {
            public Data[] data { get; set; }
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public string[] name { get; set; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I believe your JSON test string is not formed correctly, I have checked it on http://jsonlint.com/ and it proves invalid.

Now, I recently had big issues working with JSON but this website helped me a lot
 http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Hope it helps :)

### TEST EXAMPLE

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Datum
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string created_time { get; set; }
    }
    public class Paging
    {
        public string next { get; set; }
    }
    public class Music
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        public Paging paging { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Music music { get; set; }
    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string _token = "BAACEdEose0cBAE8U2tleN51ZBd8g8nBsUPVinB0dYFC2WfsGmbp2x8Vl6ZAynV81IXdZB0PkZCfFscjGjLvg8zSj1FMSi6E7al5sMLUDpZA5ZCR3rWJJjdUYxx3sdLUIaq1BJ8hGjrKPyVW6pEtp96mDmwF2vLnrivcrofvQLO4YNEqpj23Rb5gv7GwRYSbVnplKsg0dHAGS79iAp4ZBZAarwuVpSbNfZBcwZD";
            string _url = "https://graph.facebook.com/YOURID?fields=music.fields(name)&access_token=" + _token;
            string _json = wc.DownloadString(_url);

            RootObject jsonObject= json.Deserialize<RootObject>(_json);

            Response.Write(jsonObject.music.data.First().name);

            Response.Write(_json);

        }
```

Once you have your jsonObject you can use LINQ to access all the properties and all the data and you can convert it into a Result if you want too.

You can use this website to create you classes from JSON http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: i have just removed my id. this is the original ( i only put this 2 first ones because the json returns all my likes from facebook related with music)

Comment: you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and that your own json to see how it is... /yourfacebookid?fields=music.fields(name)

Comment: i tried the explorer tool and the JSON i get from my own FB is valid JSON, I still think that your JSON is not well formatted. If you read the link I provided, somewhere in there it explains that the JSON serializer will encode the object properly, with that said. have you tried by removing the doublequotes and test something like this: `string test="{id: 723560709,music: {data: [{name: LOKO  ( Life Opium Kill over )...`

Comment: it could be that if you are manually serializing wrong the test string and if you were to process the string directly from FB without modification, it would be acceptable

Comment: the problem is not the json, i have tested a lot of then(straight from facebook and edited ones) and i still getting the same error.

Comment: ok I ran some tests and i think its all about the classes look at my example in my OP